# JQUERY iCheck plugin not working for dynamic radio button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, icheck

Im facing a strange problem with iCheck plugin. I've few fields with Radio Button and check boxes. I'm using iCheck plugin for  beautifying them. Everything works fine except dynamic check boxes and radios.

When I add few radio buttons dynamically and on immediately calling the iCheck function nothing is happening. But if I call the same function from firebug, its working and iCheck feature get associated with the radios. whats wrong with it.

```
/* Here my code for adding dynamic radios with class red */
$('input[type="checkbox"].red, input[type="radio"].red').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-red',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-red',
    increaseArea: '10%' // optional
});
alert(1);
```

The alert is executing and so I belive my iCheck code is also fine. But the strange thing is if I execute the above iCheck code from firebug , the radios getting binds with iCheck features. I didnt understand the problem.

**Another strange thing is when I add another set of radios, the previous set of radios which were dynamically created being bind with iCheck and the new set is still without binding. So when ever new set added, the previous set being bonded with iCheck**

***Actual Code***

```
 $('#btn_savefield').click(function () {
            var fID, m, opt, cap;
            fID = $('#<%= dd_fieldtype.ClientID %>').val();
            var fe = $('#hid_fieldedit').val();
            m = $('#cb_mandatoryfield').prop('checked');
            if (m == false) {
                m = 0;
            }
            else {
                m = 1;
            }

            var s = $('#txt_fieldoptions').val();
            opt = s.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '|');
            cap = $('#txt_fieldcaption').val();

            var tempParam, Param;
            var tempParam = { FieldTypeID: fID, fieldTitle: cap, newoptions: opt, mandatory: m };
            var param = JSON.stringify(tempParam);
            //alert(fID);
            //alert(param);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: param,
                url: "postjobs.aspx/getFieldType",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (data) {
                    //alert("error");
                    //alert(data);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var f = data.d;
                    //alert(f);
                    if (data.d != '') {
                        if (parseInt(fe) >= 0) {
                            $('#<%= div_formfields.ClientID %>').find('.form-group:eq(' + fe.toString() + ')').replaceWith(f);
                        }
                        else {

                            $('#<%= div_formfields.ClientID %> hr').before(data.d);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
            $('#Modal_newfield').modal('hide');
            alert($('input[type="checkbox"].red, input[type="radio"].red').length);
            $('input[type="checkbox"].red, input[type="radio"].red').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-red',
                radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-red',
                increaseArea: '10%' // optional
            });

        });
```

Comment: How do you add new elements? Are you sure they are available in DOM before calling iCheck() method? Is it giving you expected result (just before iCheck call): `console.log($('input[type="checkbox"].red, input[type="radio"].red').length);` ?

Comment: Can you show more `code` here?

Comment: "Another strange thing" This isn't strange, this can easily explained if you call iCheck() before new inputs get effectively added to the DOM. I guess you are appending it using any async method as `.load()`. If you want some help, you need to add all relevant code in question.

Comment: Well ajax is async...

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes.. I've added the actual code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is async, use success callback:

```
  success: function (data) {
     var f = data.d;
     //alert(f);
     if (data.d != '') {
         if (parseInt(fe) >= 0) {
             $('#<%= div_formfields.ClientID %>').find('.form-group:eq(' + fe.toString() + ')').replaceWith(f);
         } else {

             $('#<%= div_formfields.ClientID %> hr').before(data.d);
         }
     }

     alert($('input[type="checkbox"].red, input[type="radio"].red').length);
     $('input[type="checkbox"].red, input[type="radio"].red').iCheck({
         checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-red',
         radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-red',
         increaseArea: '10%' // optional
     });

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I mentioned async:false and it solved the issue. Hope you will remove the down vote for the question..

Comment: @sforsandeep don't use async false. BTW, what makes you think i downvoted question?

Comment: But that problem got fixed when I set async:false. Before that as you pointed that radios are not in DOM. 
Sorry for that... That was a false guess...

Comment: @sforsandeep please read over the net why you shouldn't use async false... I just shown you how you should do it, now if you prefer to use the worst workaround you could get, do what you want, it's up to you...